# How to write java code for To_bytes function of Teradata

Tags: java, algorithm, teradata, decoding

I cam across a situation where, I have to write a `java` code for the teradata function called `To_Bytes`. I have to write the function which will works exactly same as `To_Bytes` in tera data.

From teradata doc.

```
To_Bytes
```

Decodes a sequence of characters in a given encoding into a sequence of bits. The following encodings are supported:

- BaseX • BaseY • Base64M (MIME) • ASCII

where X is a power of 2 (for example, 2, 8, 16) and Y is not a power of 2 (for example, 10 and 36).

Example_1,

```
SELECT TO_BYTES ('5A', 'base16');
```

returns '01011010'

Example_2,

```
SELECT TO_BYTES ('-22EEVX', 'base36');
```

returns '111 1000 1000 1101 0011 0011 0010 0011'

If anyone of you has any idea how to do that, please share
, appreciate a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with smth like (not a complete solution, just a kick in the possible direction):

```
String s = "ROGER";
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();

for (int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x100 + bytes[i]).substring(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I have different encoding types which mentioned in question like BaseX • BaseY • Base64M (MIME) • ASCII